# Cannot use drop down as form input

Tags: javascript, html, select, drop-down-menu

I have this html

```
<div id="mySelect" class="select btn-group m-b" data-resize="auto">
    <button style="font-weight:700;background-color:#fff;border-style:solid;
    border-width:2px" type="button" id="expiry_month" name="expiry_month" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-white btn-sm dropdown-toggle"> <span class="dropdown-label"></span>  <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li data-value="00" data-selected="true"><a href="#">Select Month</a>
        </li>
        <li data-value="01"><a href="#">01</a>
        </li>
        <li data-value="02"><a href="#">02</a>
        </li>
        <li data-value="03"><a href="#">03</a>
        </li>
        <li data-value="04"><a href="#">04</a>
        </li>
        <li data-value="05"><a href="#">05</a>
        </li>
        <li data-value="06"><a href="#">06</a>
        </li>
        <li data-value="07"><a href="#">07</a>
        </li>
        <li data-value="08"><a href="#">08</a>
        </li>
        <li data-value="09"><a href="#">09</a>
        </li>
        <li data-value="10"><a href="#">10</a>
        </li>
        <li data-value="11"><a href="#">11</a>
        </li>
        <li data-value="12"><a href="#">12</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

this is actually a drop down menu I used instead of `<select></select>` in a form.But im not able to post the value selected in this drop down menu.Do I have to use javascript in this?Or is it possible to get the data-value directly?

tried

```
               <div id="mySelect" class="select btn-group m-b" data-resize="auto">
                    <button style="font-weight:700;background-color:#fff;border-style:solid;
border-width:2px" type="button" id="expirymonth" name="expirymonth" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-white btn-sm dropdown-toggle">
                      <span class="dropdown-label"></span> <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
              <input type="hidden" id="expiry_month" name="expiry_month"/>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li data-value="00" data-selected="true"><a href="#">Select Month</a></li>
                      <li data-value="01" ><a class="selectOption" href="#">01</a></li>
                      <li data-value="02" ><a class="selectOption" href="#">02</a></li>
             <li data-value="03" ><a class="selectOption" href="#">03</a></li>
                      <li data-value="04" ><a class="selectOption" href="#">04</a></li>
             <li data-value="05" ><a class="selectOption" href="#">05</a></li>
                      <li data-value="06" ><a class="selectOption" href="#">06</a></li>
             <li data-value="07" ><a class="selectOption" href="#">07</a></li>
                      <li data-value="08" ><a class="selectOption" href="#">08</a></li>
             <li data-value="09" ><a class="selectOption" href="#">09</a></li>
                      <li data-value="10" ><a class="selectOption" href="#">10</a></li>
             <li data-value="11" ><a class="selectOption" href="#">11</a></li>
                      <li data-value="12" ><a class="selectOption" href="#">12</a></li>


                    </ul>
                  </div>
</div>


 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(".selectOption").click(function () {
        var selectedOption = parseInt($(this).attr('data-value'), 10);

        $("#expiry_month").val(selectedOption.toString());
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: provide **selectOption** _class_ to the html Element, for which you have mentioned _attribute_ **data-value**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery for this purpose.either you could use hidden fields inside the form,get the values of the drop fown using jquery and put the value to hidden input field

Comment: Funny you accepted this complete non-answer, while not the two very.helpful answers.

Answer (score 2):

The browser will not submit the selected value because it's not a form element. It simply doesn't know there's data to be submitted.

The best way around it would be to make a hidden select whichs value get's selected, when you change something in your drop down menu.

jQuery UI does something like this in their autocomplete examples: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

This has the huge advantage that there's an easy fallback if the browser does not support javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you two ways achieve this, right now i will tell you the first one, **using a hiddenfield**

```
    <input type="hidden" id="hfSelectedMonth" value="0" />
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li data-value="00" data-selected="true"><a class="selectOption" href="#" data-value="0">Select Month</a>
       </li>
       <li data-value="01"><a class="selectOption" href="#" data-value="1">01</a>
       </li>
       <li data-value="02"><a class="selectOption" href="#" data-value="2">02</a>
       </li>
    </ul>
```

and

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(".selectOption").click(function () {
        var selectedOption = parseInt($(this).attr('data-value'), 10);
        $("#hfSelectedMonth").val(selectedOption.toString());
    });
    </script>
```

I used click on anchor **a** tag, you may do the same for **li**, as per your convienence.

Comment: var selectedOption = parseInt($(this).attr('data-value'), 10);        what is that 10 meant for

Comment: This is not working.im getting a value "0" in the input hidden field

Comment: 10 is base for decimal.

Comment: try putting alert inside the click function, then check whether you are getting any value in variable selectedOption or not, otherwise update the markup after you have made the changes. I will help you with javascript.

Comment: I have added what I tried.Im getting a null value actually

Comment: Can i ask you,why we neeed to use parseInt since its already an integer in the data-value

Comment: its a good programming practise in-case we do not mention a _data-value_ attribute or leave it blank like **data-value=""** for the anchor tags... var would always have default value of int, that is _0_.

Comment: Ok anway,Im afraid thisis not working,I have updated with what I have tried

Comment: I suggest you assign class _selectOption_ to each **li** tag and then use above java-script code